# Multiline header forcing the headrule downwards

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I am having problems with multiline headers, they are forcing the headrule downwards depending on the number of lines occupied by the header title. I want my headrule to be fixed such that it does not shift when a I write a multiline header title. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
 \fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OL]{\myheaderfooterfont\leftmark}
\fancyhead[ER]{\myheaderfooterfont\rightmark}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}% 
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{calc,pifont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document} 
        \frontmatter

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\mainmatter
\chapter{Outline of The Uonw HAUnn HUAH}
\chapter{Typing Equations and matrices in LATEX and Special keyboard characters in LATEX shshhw eeehuwhuw wjwjwj whij3ooeok i3jijei ejeejedijeejo
}
\section{Equations and Matrices}
\subsection{Equations}
\AmS{} package is loaded to typeset Higher Mathematics equations. A single equation can be on one line, several lines (no alignment) and several lines (with alignment). Also equation groups can be without alignment, with simple alignment and or multiple alignment. Equations can also be in cases.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
 \begin{split}
        \lvert I_2 \rvert &= \left\lvert \int_{0}^T \psi(t)
        \left\{ u(a, t) - \int_{\gamma(t)}^a \frac{d\theta}{k}
        (\theta, t) \int_{a}^\theta c (\xi) u_t (\xi, t) \,d\xi
        \right\} dt \right\rvert \\
        &\le C_6 \Biggl\lvert
        \left\lvert f \int_\Omega \left\lvert
        \widetilde{S}^{-1,0}_{a,-} W_2(\Omega, \Gamma_l)
        \right\rvert \ \right\rvert
        \left\lvert \lvert u \rvert
        \overset{\circ}{\to} W_2^{\widetilde{A}} (\Omega; \Gamma_r,T)
        \right\rvert \Biggr\rvert
\end{split} \end{equation}
\subsection{Matrices}

Here are samples of the matrix environments,
\verb+matrix+, \verb+pmatrix+, \verb+bmatrix+, \verb+Bmatrix+, \verb+vmatrix+
and \verb+Vmatrix+:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
    \begin{matrix}
        \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
    \end{matrix}\quad
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
    \end{pmatrix}\quad
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
    \end{bmatrix}\quad
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
    \end{Bmatrix}\quad
    \begin{vmatrix}
        \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
    \end{vmatrix}\quad
    \begin{Vmatrix}
        \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
    \end{Vmatrix}
\end{equation}
\section{Special keyboard characters}
\LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `geometry` package to have a larger space for the header. For example:

```
\usepackage[
%showframe,% show margins
includehead,
top=10mm, %  with includehead from page top to head
headheight = 3\baselineskip,% header's height
headsep = 5mm,% from header to body text
]{geometry}
```

**Short title**

[image: a]

**Long title**

[image: b]

This is the complete code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}  

\usepackage[
%showframe,% show margins
includehead,
top=10mm,  % with includehead from page top to head 
headheight = 3\baselineskip,% header's height
headsep = 5mm,% from header to body text
]{geometry} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\myheaderfooterfont\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\myheaderfooterfont\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}% 
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{calc,pifont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document} 
    \frontmatter
    
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Outline of The Uonw HAUnn HUAH}
    \kant[2-10]
    
    \chapter{Typing Equations and matrices in LATEX and Special keyboard characters in LATEX shshhw eeehuwhuw wjwjwj whij3ooeok i3jijei ejeejedijeejo}
    \section{Equations and Matrices}
    \subsection{Equations}
    \AmS{} package is loaded to typeset Higher Mathematics equations. A single equation can be on one line, several lines (no alignment) and several lines (with alignment). Also equation groups can be without alignment, with simple alignment and or multiple alignment. Equations can also be in cases.
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
        \begin{split}
            \lvert I_2 \rvert &= \left\lvert \int_{0}^T \psi(t)
            \left\{ u(a, t) - \int_{\gamma(t)}^a \frac{d\theta}{k}
            (\theta, t) \int_{a}^\theta c (\xi) u_t (\xi, t) \,d\xi
            \right\} dt \right\rvert \\
            &\le C_6 \Biggl\lvert
            \left\lvert f \int_\Omega \left\lvert
            \widetilde{S}^{-1,0}_{a,-} W_2(\Omega, \Gamma_l)
            \right\rvert \ \right\rvert
            \left\lvert \lvert u \rvert
            \overset{\circ}{\to} W_2^{\widetilde{A}} (\Omega; \Gamma_r,T)
            \right\rvert \Biggr\rvert
    \end{split} \end{equation}
    \subsection{Matrices}
    
    Here are samples of the matrix environments,
    \verb+matrix+, \verb+pmatrix+, \verb+bmatrix+, \verb+Bmatrix+, \verb+vmatrix+
    and \verb+Vmatrix+:
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
        \begin{matrix}
            \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
        \end{matrix}\quad
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
        \end{pmatrix}\quad
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
        \end{bmatrix}\quad
        \begin{Bmatrix}
            \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
        \end{Bmatrix}\quad
        \begin{vmatrix}
            \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
        \end{vmatrix}\quad
        \begin{Vmatrix}
            \vartheta& \varrho\\\varphi& \varpi
        \end{Vmatrix}
    \end{equation}
    \section{Special keyboard characters}
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon Dispa, it worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of theincludehead option in the geometry package?

Comment: @itc To facilitate the setup. So `top` goes from the top border of the page to the top of the reserved space for the header. Uncomment `showframe` to see all three top spaces defined.

Comment: Noted with thanks.